# can't get web response with https

Tags: c#, ssl, https, certificate

I use this code to get web content but get exception at `WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();`

```
HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.ecfr.gov");
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (Object obj, X509Certificate X509certificate, X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors errors)
{
    return true;
};
myRequest.Method = "GET";
WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();
StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();
myResponse.Close();
```

I know it needs SSL/TLS Certificate, but I want to know why I still get an error?

https://www.ecfr.gov

Comment: Any time you “get exception” you need to tell us what the exception is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var result = client.GetAsync("https://www.ecfr.gov").Result;
        var str = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
```